# Incompatible json gem versions in Rails when installing Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, stripe-payments

I´m trying to install Stripe gem in my Rails 4.0 app, but when running bundle install I´m getting this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    json (1.8.0)

  In Gemfile:
    stripe (>= 0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      json (~> 1.8.1) x86-mingw32
```

I added this entry to my gemfile:

```
# stripe
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'
```

and I do confirm my gemfile.lock has this entry:

```
json (1.8.0)
```

How can I upgrade it? I´m not so skilled with this config files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

You have just to run:

```
 bundle update json
```